# Python 3 OpenCV Color Object Detect with defined edges

Tags: python, opencv

My python code takes a screenshot of by desktop and looks for a red rectangle on a black background, when I use the cv2.findcountours it doesn't return an exact sized rectangle, it seems to be distorted. I would like to obtain the exact area of the shape. Also, the image on my screenshot has no pixelation and borders are sharp.
Thanks for your help!

```
frame_TS_new_raw = np.array(sct.grab(monitor_TS_new))
frame_TS_new = cv2.cvtColor(frame_TS_new_raw, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2RGB)

green_mask_TS_new = cv2.inRange(frame_TS_new,green_lower_range, green_upper_range)

# find contours for New TS
cnts_green_new = cv2.findContours(green_mask_TS_new.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts_green_new = cnts_green_new[0] if imutils.is_cv2() else cnts_green_new[1]
if len(cnts_green_new) > 0:
    for c in cnts_green_new:
        # if the contour is not sufficiently large, ignore it
        if cv2.contourArea(c) > 100:
            area = cv2.contourArea(c)
```

**screenshot of the masked and unmasked**

[image]

The image on the left is raw screenshot and the image on the right is the masked.

Comment: What do you mean "image on the left" and "image on the right" -- there's just one giant white image with two tiny blobs in the top left corner...

Comment: Yes thank you I edited the image to make it larger. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To find area of red rectangle in the image you can do as:

- extract red channel of the image
- threshold red channel
- count number of nonzero pixels

Example code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('vju0v.png')
img = np.array(img) # convert to numpy array
red = img[:,:,2]    # extract red channel
rect = np.float32(red > 200)   # find red pixels
area = np.sum(rect)    # count nonzero pixels

print('Area = ' + str(area))

cv2.imshow('Red Channel',rect)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: Is there any way that I can use this method of counting the pixels but use a range because I need to detect three different colors of red but I dont want to overlap other colors (dark red and gray for example)?

Comment: you can define your range as rect = np.float32(red > 200 and red < 225)

Comment: What about a range for the other colors like if I want red to be from 30 to 255, green 0 to 100, blue 0 to 85?

Comment: you can get three channels as red = img[:,:,2] and green = img[:,:,1] and blue = img[:,:,0] and use your range to get colors

Comment: I get this error:    rect = np.float32(red > 30 and red < 255)   # find red pixels
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()